# How to bind to another event after ajax call in jquery

Tags: jquery, flot

I'm creating a graph using flot javascript library. I have enabled clickable  event and the div is binded to plotclick event. So, when a datapoint is clicked, an ajax call is made and the result is used to replace the current div. After this i need to bind the div to a new event.

I tried to call bind, but it is still bound to old callback. When i call unbind and bind, the new callback is not called.

```
var handleTeacherClick = function( event, pos, item ) {
        if( typeof item != "undefined" && item ) { 
            var user_id = jQuery( 'input[name="id' + item.datapoint[0] + '"]' ).val();
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: BASEPATH + 'index.php/ajax/home/latest',
                data: { "user_id": user_id },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function ( result ) {
                    jQuery.plot(jQuery('#stats_prog'), 
                        result.progress_data, result.progress_options);
                    jQuery.plot(jQuery('#stats_perf'),
                        result.performance_data, result.performance_options);
                    jQuery('.stats_title').
                        html('<span class="stats_title">'+
                            ' >> Chapter '+Math.ceil(item.datapoint[0])+'</span>');
                        jQuery('#stats_prog')./*unbind("plotclick").*/
                            bind('plotclick', statClickHandler );
                        jQuery('#stats_perf')./*unbind("plotclick"). */
                            bind( 'plotclick', statClickHandler );
                },
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case use `live` instead of bind event handler

Answer (score 0):

For the new elements, you should use either of [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/). In case you are using a plugin, you will to use [`livequery`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just calling `unbind('plotclick')`, explicitly including the function you want to unbind (using `unbind('plotclick',functionVar)`):

```
jQuery('#stats_prog').unbind("plotclick", handleTeacherClick).
                        bind('plotclick', statClickHandler );
```